# Variable checking in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am fairly new to the JSP scene, but have been programming in other languages for a few years.  I am writing an application where I am passing a different variable to java based on a selection option.  My main question was where to do the variable checking to see which value to pass?

Here is my current state of value checking (I am currently rewriting it in JSTL as I found sciplets are bad practice).

```
    if (request.getParameter("Freq").equals("Minutes")) {
        runOn = request.getParameter("numberOfMinutes");
    } else if (request.getParameter("Freq").equals("Weekly")) {
        runOn = request.getParameter("dayOfWeek");
    } else if (request.getParameter("Freq").equals("Monthly")) {
        runOn = request.getParameter("dayOfMonth");
    } else {
        runOn = "-1";
    }
```

Should this sort of check be done on the jsp page, in javascript, or somewhere else?  Looking for a best practice kind of answer.

Side question: Right now, I create a number of different drop down boxes and hide/unhide them using an onChange function in javascript.  Would it be better to have one list box where the options change in javascript or keep the current system?  Essentially the list boxes are asking the user what day they want their process to run. So if frequency is weekly, a list box with the days of the week would show, but if they have month selected, a list of numbers from 1 to 31 shows. It could all be done with one list box that changes its options when the 'frequency' drop down changes.  Again, I'm looking for a best practice answer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't get your question... What do you mean with HTML page etc.? It's already stated in the JSP?

Comment: Like having it on the jsp page.  I am just wondering if there is a best practice to do variable checks. Is it typically done with jstl tags, a javascript function, or is there somewhere else you do it?

Comment: I would do it in JSTL if you have the chance to use it. Try to avoid using Javascript when possible.

Comment: I state I am currently re writing it in JSTL. I'm more wondering if it is best practice to do so there or if there is an even better way or 'more right' way to do it.  If this sort of value check is best done in JSTL, than cool, but I wanted to check with community to see if it was.

Comment: It just depends. If you can use JSTL, you should do it. It's better than using things in Javascript if you can achieve the same with it. So yes, it's a best practice when you are able to use it (not all projects can use JSP's, like for example in Wordpress).

Comment: Alright, cool.  That's what was wondering. Thank you.